# How to set Gmail gadget extractor to use multiple params name/value in COB extensions

Tags: google-apps-marketplace

Maybe a silly question but when you want to publish a gmail contextual gadget on google-app-market place, the COB extensions ask for one param name and value per extractor.
How can I specify two names and then two respective values ?

I'm not sure adding 2 extractors will do what I want...

I need one extractor with a filter on 2 params. It worked well for development with the manifest, but I don't know how to replicate my manifest on the form below:

[image: COB form]

My manifest part:

```
<Extension id="Extractor" type="contextExtractor">
  <Name>My Name</Name>
  <Url>google.com:HttpLinkExtractor</Url>
  <Param name="host" value="example.com|www.example.com"/>
  <Param name="path" value="^\/\w{16}$|^\/\w{16}\/"/>
  <Triggers ref="Gadget"/>
  <Scope ref="emailSubject"/>
  <Scope ref="emailBody"/>
  <Container name="mail"/>
</Extension>
```

thanks

Comment: Ok it seems adding 2 extractors is the way to go

Comment: Ok back to square 1. I spoke too quickly, it does work. It just kills the gadget...

Comment: Could you please suggest what steps you followed since there is no extractor file ?

Comment: Yes there is no extraction file, that's the problem. The steps to follow is simply try to publish the plugin on the market place. In dev mode, I have an extractor file so I can do whatever I want, but when I want to publish Google doesn't ask for an extractor file but directly for the extractor param and value

Comment: Did you try putting this as the COB Extractor? From your manifest: `google.com:HttpLinkExtractor`

Comment: Have you found a solution? Thanks.